# Undefined variable when using cURL in a function in php

Tags: php, curl

Im working on a simple php script that will return the number of search results from google search on a specific string (using cURL). When i keep my code global everything works fine but as soon as i create a function I get an error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: resultTagId in C:\wamp\www\tag.php on line 24
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\tag.php on line 24
```

here is my code

```
<?php

$resultTagId = "resultStats"; 
$encodedNames = $_GET['names'];
$names=json_decode($encodedNames);


    getNumber($names[0]);

function getNumber($name) // before i used to set $name = $names[0] and everything worked fine
{
    $name = str_replace(" ", "+", trim($name));

    $url='http://www.google.com/search?q='.$name.'&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML( $data );
    $resultsTag =  $dom->getElementById($resultTagId)->nodeValue;

    $results =  preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","" ,$resultsTag);
    echo $results;
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: `function getNumber($resultTagId,$name)` ???

Comment: oh wow i didnt realize that could be a problem... so used to coding in java -.-

Comment: @Xitcod13: how java justifies that? Variables scope in java is even more strict.

Comment: @zerkms  this example would work just fine in java.

Comment: @Xitcod13: in java you couldn't create that. Probably you confuse it with javascript

Comment: @zerkms I know you couldnt create the functionality but you could create the syntax and the syntax would allow for the use of the variable inside the function without specifying it is global

Comment: @Xitcod13: don't you confuse it with javascript? java != javascript.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18892/discussion-between-xitcod13-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of ways that you can do this (including using a [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), which tends to make things messy), but the best way is to pass your variable as an argument.

Change the arguments for the function:

```
function getNumber($name, $tagId) {
```

And when you're calling the function, pass your variable:

```
getNumber($names[0], $resultTagId)
```

Comment: -1 for not mentioning passing via argument and using globals instead

Comment: Sure, I'll edit in passing by argument. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: not many, but you've chosen the worst :-)